# getting the currentday of code to work

Tags: java

I'm having some issues with getting days of the week to show.
My code is:

```
public static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7
private NumberDisplay day
public String getCurrentDay()
```

I'm stuck here what would go here to make this work?

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to return the current date as a String eg. "Sunday for day 0, Monday for day 1 and stuff.

Comment: if you want today's day, use this `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()`  (Java8)

Comment: i understand but this is a question for an assignment im doing, its clockdissplay assignment and this part is the date asking.

Comment: my constructor was

Comment: my constructor was publicDayDisplay(int dayToSet) {                                     dayToSet = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using LocalDateTime class.

```
      // Get the current date and time
      LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
      DayOfWeek dayOfWeek=currentTime.getDayOfWeek();

      int dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.getValue();
```

**Please note this uses DateTime API of java 8. it will not work in older jdk versions.**

Comment: thank you, how would i increment the date? like public void incrementDay() which is suppose to increment the day like sunday to monday.  the code is used for some reason gave me an error.  im not sure what do put in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Java 8 installed, you can go for `Calendar` . It works in earlier versions as well.

Code would be like below:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `Calendar` and `Date` from `java.util` package, here is an example function:

```
String getCurrentWeekDay()
{
    String[] weekDays = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    Date today = new Date();
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(today);
    int weekday=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return weekDays[weekday];
}
```